# How to make connection With mail server in oracle PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, phpmailer, mail-server

i have my own mail server with IP,Host,Username,Password. So i want to make connection with my mail server for just check mail server is active or not.
please suggest me tutorial.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is "oracle PHP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to check it the mail server is active, use the [fsockopen function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) :

```
$fp = fsockopen("10.0.0.1", 25, $errno, $errstr, 15);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}else{
 echo "Mail Server is active";
}
```